# Setting the background of a Button view in XML makes the button not-clickable

Tags: java, android, xml, button, android-activity

I have a button defined in my XML file.  The button works exactly like you would expect...that is until I add the line at the bottom (android:background="drawable/leftarrow1").  Then the button is no longer clickable in the activity, but the new background shows up like I want.

What gives?

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/switch_left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/leftarrow1" />
```

Here is the click code for reference

```
Button switchLeft = (Button) findViewById(R.id.switch_left);
switchLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       Log.w(this.getClass().getName(), "clicked left arrow");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I works totally normal. Every click gets recorded.

My guess is that you use a solid image file (.png, .jpeg) as your background. If you just use such an image it will never change when clicked or selected. For that there is the state-list drawable described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).

In that XML file you define the images to show upon a specific state like selected, clicked and so on.

Another tip. If you want to check out the functionality of buttons for example use this kind of code.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TestButton extends Activity {

    Context ctx = null;
    Button btn = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.buttonbackground);

        ctx = getApplication();

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.switch_left);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Toast.makeText(ctx, "Button clicked", 5000).show();
               // Log.w(this.getClass().getName(), "clicked left arrow");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It will be easier for you to recognize the event as a toast message is a more visual feedback.

Comment: I can not get that Toast to work...tried getApplicationContext() too.  Also, yes I am using a png/jgp for the background.  Do I have to implement all state-list drawables in order for this to work?

Comment: Note: I don't care about what the button looks like, I care about the code firing when I click it...which it isn't doing :(

Comment: @user432209: No you don't have to implement a state-list drawable. It was just a pointer to a more elegant way to display the background however it is not related to your problem. I've seen your second question where you mentioned that you have a custom view which holds the log message. If it is related to it please tell me so I can answer the correct question.

Comment: Bah, my problem was stupid...I had two buttons using the same resource, and thus I was implementing two on click methods for the same resource which totally screwed it up.  Thanks for getting me to the ultimate solution....but no, my other problem isn't solved.

Answer (score 0):

hey buddy for showing buttons with images there is a ImageButton available. 
try this in xml file.

Comment: He wants to have a custom background not an icon on this button.

Comment: true octavian but from his resource file it seems that he is setting the background initially, hence i suggested the same.